# Knex, Postgres, and STRING_ARRAY: getting different results

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, string-aggregation

I was testing out a query here using STRING_ARRAY: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/952405/1

Also here:

```
SELECT   to_char(workshop_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') date, STRING_AGG(first_name || ' ' || last_name, ', ')
FROM     parents_workshops
JOIN     parents ON parents.id = ANY(parents_workshops.parents_id)
WHERE    teacher_id = 1
GROUP BY date
```

The above works as expected. However, when I run that on my Node.JS/Express server using Knex, I get an odd response.

Here's the code:

//teachers.js

```
const findParentWorkshops = id =>
    knex.raw(
        `SELECT to_char(workshop_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') date, STRING_AGG(first_name || ' ' || last_name, ', ')FROM parents_workshops
        JOIN parents ON parents.id = ANY (parents_workshops.parents_id)
        WHERE teacher_id = ${id} GROUP BY date`
    );
```

// teacherController.js

```
const getParentWorkshops = (req, res, next) => {
    const teacherId = req.params.id;

    Teacher.findParentWorkshops(teacherId)
        .then(workshops => {    
            res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                status: 200,
                message: `Parents' workshops found`,
                length: workshops.length,
                workshops,
            });
        })
        .catch(next);
};
```

//teacherRoutes.js

```
router
    .route(`/teachers/:id/parents-workshops`)
    .get(getParentWorkshops)
    .post(postParentWorkshop);
```

I expected the same output as from the sqlfiddle above. However, I got this back (NB, the expected data should be the value for the 'workshops' key:

```
{
"ok": true,
"status": 200,
"message": "Parents' workshops found",
"workshops": {
"command": "SELECT",
"rowCount": 0,
"oid": null,
"rows": [],
"fields": [
{
"name": "date",
"tableID": 0,
"columnID": 0,
"dataTypeID": 25,
"dataTypeSize": -1,
"dataTypeModifier": -1,
"format": "text"
},
{
"name": "string_agg",
"tableID": 0,
"columnID": 0,
"dataTypeID": 25,
"dataTypeSize": -1,
"dataTypeModifier": -1,
"format": "text"
}
],
"_parsers": [
null,
null
],
"RowCtor": null,
"rowAsArray": false
}
```

}

I've searched around a bit, and found that this is the format that INSERT queries typically return for node-postgres, however I have yet to find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your function `findParentWorkshops` is returning (part of) the query definition, rather than the query result. So it isn't actually executing.

Below I've explicitly wrapped it in a promise, and included `return` statements, and it executes producing a result. I'm using node v6, perhaps your more recent version operates a little different, or you are using bluebird for your promises?

Also, note the `.on('query'` clause. I use this while debugging. It ensures the SQL generated is what I expect, and it shows that the query is actually executing.

I leave the `.on('query-error'` clause in for good runtime error hints, but actually log via a file based mechanism.

```
function findParentWorkshops(id) {
    console.log('Debug 00 .findParentWorkshops');

    return Promise.resolve()
        .then( function() { 
            console.log('Debug 01');
            return db.raw( `SELECT to_char(workshop_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') date, STRING_AGG(first_name || ' ' || last_name, ', ')FROM parents_workshops
                JOIN parents ON parents.id = ANY (parents_workshops.parents_id)
                WHERE teacher_id = ? GROUP BY date` , [id]) 
                // debug error reporting, remove for production.
                .on('query', function(data) {
                    console.log('Debug81 query:', data);
                })
                // runtime error reporting, execution is not interrupted.
                .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
                    console.log("Error89 .on.query-error", {"obj":obj, "ex":ex} );
                })
        })
};
```